# Command: tail file.txt '

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, debian

first up, a linux newbie.

I made a typo and I have no idea what I've walked into, and documentation to no avail.

Screen shot:
[image]

running

```
man tail
```

unfortunately provided no help either.

what is this command doing?

Exit by using ctrl + C

Comment: Why did the man page of the `tail` command not help?

Comment: The command opens and reads a file (or socket) and prints the last lines (the tail) to the terminal. Most likely you have an `alias` defined that translates `tail` to `tail -f` so that the command does _not_ exist but wait for new lines to appear which it will output again. Have a try with `alias tail` to find out.

Comment: The first line of `man tail` :  `tail - output the last part of files`

Comment: First tell what are you upto? What you were intended to do with `tail` ? It supposed to show last 10 lines of a file but you made a mess their by adding `'`.

Comment: Unclosed quote `'`. Type a quote `'` alone and press `enter` and you will get the same thing.

Comment: adding ' was an accident. it took a while to get out of the process that it went into. What is bash doing when that happens?

Comment: @arkascha - its clear to me now that ' is not some kind of option or argument for the command tail. Seeing as it adopted the observed behaviour, i assumed man would detail that usage of tail, and it didnt. no where seems to explain what it moved into that mode, for want of a better way to explain it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I actually msised that `'`. That is _not_ an argument interpreted by the `tail` command, but is processed by the shell you work in. It expects that the command is not yet finished (you opened a string literal but never closed it). So it keeps on asking for you to continue typing that literal.

Comment: okay. If we use ' and leave it open, bash lets you type what ever you want to give it a literal, including newline characters without the command trying to run - because this is a string literal. am I on the right track?

Comment: @arkascha - where should a question like this go? I think it shouldn't be here, this is well and truely a newbie question.

Comment: You are on the right track, yes.

Comment: Newbie question are fine, but this is a place to ask programming questions. You may want to try one of the Unix or Linux sister pages in the stack exchange universe.

Comment: okay, cool - how do i pull this question down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apostrophe ( ' ) has nothing to do with tail command. What it really does is it allows you to insert multi line text in commands.

```
$ echo 'hello
> world'
hello
world
```

Don't forget to add an apostrophe at end to enclose the text.